# How to check TWO key pressed in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, keypress, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a Matlab GUI with many buttons. Now I want to set some shotcuts to the button.
Actually I can check for one button and it works fine.
My questin is how I can check if two buttons will be press?

Something like CTRL + KEY.
It mustn´t the CTRL key =) It could be any key combination.

Thanks for help.
Sorry for my english.

To check for one key I use this code:

```
key1 = get(gcf,'CurrentKey');

if(strcmp (key1 ,'k'))
%CODE HERE
end
```

I have try something like this (for the keys k and q):

```
key2 = get(gcf,'CurrentKey');

keystr = [key1 + key2];

if(strcmp(keystr, 'kq'))
%CODE HERE
end
```

The value of key1 change, if you press another button on the keyboard.
So the && operator is never fullfilled.

Comment: What code do you use to check for one button pressed? I don't know much about this but wouldn't simply the && operator work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not fully generic, but I think this should do the trick:

First determine whether control is pressed [as shown by @Pursuit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10113213/983722) (probably works for several keys)

```
modifiers = get(gcf,'currentModifier');        
ctrlIsPressed = ismember('control',modifiers);
```

Then just check the current key, as you already did and combine the result. In the end it could look something like this:

```
modifiers = get(gcf,'currentModifier');        
key1 = get(gcf,'CurrentKey');

if(strcmp (key1 ,'k')) && ismember('control',modifiers)
    %CODE HERE
end
```

Comment: thats a nice solution. But on every try I get a 0 if I press the control key and if I press an other key.

Comment: @user3510014 Do you manage to get it working if you only press the control key? If not please check the linked question and see what you do differently.

Comment: I´ve did it only with the control key. What does mean the comment in the linked question (Use an actual figure number if known)?

Comment: If I check the value of modifiers it´s an empty cell array-